# Java Precedence between logical AND &&, & and XOR OR ^

Tags: java

```
boolean aaa = true ^ true & true ^ true ;
System.out.println(aaa); // The result is true

boolean aaa = true ^ true && true ^ true ;
System.out.println(aaa); // The result is false
```

My question is even when both && and & are logical operator AND, & still have higher precedence than && since it also is bitwise operator?

Comment: It works exactly as you calculated. And your question is "why?" even when you already stated the answer- precedence / order of operations?

Comment: I just want to confirm my thought is correct or not since I not so sure about it.

Comment: I always used parens with this type of thing, just as I always use {} for simple loops and if clauses.  Doing both helps prevent unexpected consequences.

Comment: This is documented. It is futile, and risky, to ask questions like this on the Internet when official specifications and tutorials are available. You might get a wrong answer, or no answer at all. And, as a general rule, you won't find a programming language where the operator precedence varies according to semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

> & has higher precedence than && since it is also the bitwise-and operator.

That is also compliant with other C-like languages. Note that C and C++ did not define a logical-& operator.